statements that can be accepted by finitists.
"On the finitist view, the formula $\exists n P(n)$ is meaningful only when it is used as a statement specifying how to calculate an $n$ for which $P(n)$ is true".
It is mentioned as above in one of my philosopy of mathematics books. In this situation, I just wonder that when the formula $\exists n P(n)\to\exists m Q(m)$ can be valid by finitists then. My interpretation of this formula in a finitist argument is "If there is an $n$ for which $P(n)$ is true, then we can have a finitistic way that generates an $m$ for which $Q(m)$ is true (such $n$ is not required to be exist explicitly, but the $m$ has to be exhibit explicitly using the term $n$)".
In this interpretation, the statement "if we can have a finitistic proof of $Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC+I)$, then we always have a proof of $\lnot Con(ZFC)$" is valid on the finitist view, since if there is a finitistic proof of $Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC+I)$ then we can prove this in $ZF$, ($I$ denotes the proposition "there is an inaccessible cardinal")
so $ZF\vdash Con(\ulcorner ZFC\urcorner)\to Con(\ulcorner ZFC+I\urcorner)$
,  $ZFC+I\vdash Con(\ulcorner ZFC\urcorner)\to Con(\ulcorner ZFC+I\urcorner)$, hence by the second incompleteness theorem $\lnot Con(ZFC+I)$, with this and the hypothesis we finally have a proof of $\lnot Con(ZFC)$. This argument ensures that we can always have a finitistic way that deduces $\lnot Con(ZFC)$ whenever we have a finitistic proof of  $Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC+I)$.
My question is: Can this whole argument be accepted by finitists?

Sounds more like "constructivist" to me than it does "finitist".
